# Can anyone explain why my question still hasn't been re-opened?

Tags: support, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

After rewriting my question, I want to get it re-opened but no body is voting to re-open. Any ideas?

[My Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786366/is-it-possible-to-mirror-an-iphone-screen-to-a-ipad-wirelessly) (now 10k only)

Comment: Maybe because it is not a question?

Comment: Your question is, quite simply, `Has anyone figured out how to program an iPhone app so that It interacts with a local iPad.` where the answer is either `yes` or `no`. What are you asking? for teh codez? for resources? for a program that does what you want?

Answer (score 11):

After your edit, you question isn't off topic any more.

However, there are some ongoing problems:

- **It's badly phrased.**

  You don't actually ask for what you need. Don't ask *Has anyone...?*. Ask *How can I...?*.

  Be clear about what you need. (And include a question mark somewhere.)
- **It shows no research effort.**

  By itself, this might or might not get your question closed. If your question is overly broad as a result (I don't know enough about iP[ao]d to know for sure), it might get closed as **not a real question**.

  But closed or not, a question with no research effort will earn you downvotes.

  See also: [Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553)

Once you fixed your question, wait a little. Edits bump your question to the front page, so it might accumulate reopen votes.

If it doesn't, but you're **certain** that your question should get reopened, you can always flag for Moderator attention and ask for the question to get reopened.

Comment: In its current state, it would probably still be closed by users knowledgable on the subject, because it really needs to be narrowed down. "Has anyone figured out how to program an iPhone app so that It interacts with a local iPad." is the core question, and it doesn't state what kind of interaction is wanted here. Do you want touch gestures in an application on one device to activate something on a matching application on the other? Does "local" mean devices connected via Bluetooth or WiFi? A lot more detail needs to be provided before we can give a good answer here.

Answer (score 9):

It looks like a [gimme-codez](/questions/tagged/gimme-codez) question.

#### [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Also note that the [original version of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/10786366/1) sounded more like a recommendation for an *app*, not necessarily for a programmatic solution, hence the off-topic closing.

Comment: I think you misspelled `[gimme-teh-codez]`.

Comment: @Dennis :-P hehe